# Moving GIS Data to AWS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, amazon-web-services

I am an ArcGIS Desktop user and a layman to cloud computing. Our GIS data is currently hosted on a server and recently our IT dept started to look at possibilities to get rid of this server and move all the GIS data (vector & raster) to Amazon cloud. I am not sure how ArcGIS can connect to the data in cloud.

Is it an easy setup or does it require extra stuff?

I googled a bit and most articles I found are related to ArcGIS server. We don't have ArcGIS Server here.

Comment: ArcGIS Enterprise uses AWS > http://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/cloud/amazon/what-is-arcgis-server-on-aws.htm please contact esri for costs and support

Comment: You **don't** want your local Desktop node connecting to data in the cloud.  You can create a Desktop node in the cloud, and connect to the data there, though it is likely to be quite pricey (you can't use S3 for data processing).